# Type-inferring a delegate argument with unknow number of known-typed arguments

Tags: d

If you define a function that accepts a delegate, D can type-infer the delegate arguments when you call that function. So if I write a function with the signature:

```
void foo(void delegate(int,string) dlg)
```

I can call it using:

```
foo((a,b){});
```

and D will infer that `a` is `int` and `b` is `string`.

But what if I don't know in advance how many arguments the delegate will have? if I write

```
void foo(T...)(void delegate(T) dlg)
```

I can call:

```
foo((int a,string b,char c,boolean d){});
```

But I had to specify the types for each argument.

Now, I want `foo` to accept a delegate with **any** number of arguments - all of the same type. So I can call:

```
foo((a,b,c,d,e,f,g){});
```

and D will infer that `a` to `g` are all `string`s.

Note that what I need is **not** a varidaic function. `dlg` itself does not accept any number of arguments, it is `foo` that accepts a delegate with any number of arguments.

Is it possible to do this in D?

**EDIT**:
Actually, it would be better if I can define a default argument, so I can write

```
foo((a,b,int c,d){});
```

and `a`,`b` and `d` will be strings while `c` will be `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an enhancement request. But for now you can pass it at compile-time as an alias:

```
import std.stdio;

void foo(alias dlg)()
{
    dlg(1, 2.0, [3], "a");
    dlg(1.0, 2, [[3]], "b");
}

void main()
{
    foo!((a, b, c, d) { writefln("%s %s %s %s", a, b, c, d); } )();
}
```

Comment: Techincally, it is not the same, as no type inference happens in this case. Aliased delegate becomes a template and is instantiated on usual per-usage basis. As far as I have understood, Idan asks about something slightly different.

Comment: Actually I can use this, but for some reason when I do it like this `isCallable!dlg` returns false so I can't use `ParameterIdentifierTuple!dlg` and `ParameterTypeTuple!dlg` to get the delegate's parameter types and names. Is there a way to solve this, or do I have to parse `dlg.stringof` myself to get that info?

Comment: OK, the problem was that `dlg` is a template, not a delegate. If I use `dlg(string,string,string,string)` I can get it's parameter trait data. How can I tell how many template arguments a template has?

Comment: I am afraid this kind of functionality may be not covered by Phobos/__traits yet. If you know allowed template parameter types such utility template is pretty trivial to write, most generic sounds rthaer tricky though.

Comment: @Idan Arye: This problem is filed as http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=9608